# Can you setup a match where both the home and away team is the same?

Tags: fifa-12, fifa-13, fifa-11

We are holding a competition and need to keep things as even as possible, so is it e.g. possible to play a two player match between Barcelona and Barcelona in Fifa 11, 12 and 13?

Comment: This was possible in FIFA 97; I'd be surprised if the feature was since removed

Comment: @badp You'd be suprised to see what small features go in and out of games between versions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that feature is still in the game. Any team in the game can be played against itself.